# R Replace a value with a character from another data.table

Tags: r

Here I met some problems in R about replacement coding.

Here is the original data.table. There are two datatables:

```
dt1 <- data.table(V1 = c(1,"A"))
dt2 <- data.table("1" = c(4,5,6), "A" = c("c","d","e"))
```

Now I want to replace values in dt1 with value in dt2 by matching relationship.

The desired output should be:

```
dt3 <- data.table(V1 = c("4,5,6", "c,d,e"))
```

That is, I want to replace values in dt1 with all values in the corresponding column in dt2. And this is a simple example, I want to apply it to the whole data.table in R.

I met so big trouble in dealing with this, so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way from your input to desired output.

```
dt1[, V1 := sapply(dt2, paste, collapse = ',')[V1]]


# Test
all.equal(dt1, dt3)
[1] TRUE
```

PS. Are you sure that storing the values separated by a comma in a string is the best?

Comment: Not the best, I will split the string later. In fact, I want to replace V1 = c(1, "A") to V1 = c(4, 5, 6, "a", "b", "c"), but I don't know how to do that, so I think the first step is to replace one value with one string containing all values in a column. If so, is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

We may do

```
dt1[, V1  := unlist(lapply(V1, function(x) toString(dt2[[x]])))]
dt1
        V1
1: 4, 5, 6
2: c, d, e
```